# R - CSV error - unexpected numeric constant

Tags: r, csv

I have a simple csv file with around 20K+ values separated by commas. When I try to load the values in R, it gives me the error:

```
r:3: unexpected numeric constant
```

Here is the simple command of R that I executed

```
someThing <- c(0.080172405,0.06233087,0.04315185,0.0652015,0.03201301.......n)
n= 70,000 values
```

I cannot copy paste all the 20K+ values here. I googled this error and there is no special character or another thing except for some floating values.

### EDIT

http://pastebin.com/FVkUV6kY

Comment: What is invalid entry? and how can I find it? All the values are greater than 0 and they are floating.

Comment: Can you post the entire data on a pastebin site?

Comment: LINK is added - http://pastebin.com/FVkUV6kY

Comment: So you have a CSV file with a single row of comma separated numerics? If so, that is hardly ideal. I would sed the ',' for a new line character and read it in as a table. That way you will be able to pin point easier which value is throwing the parsing off by identifying the line.

Comment: You said "..Here is the simple command of R that I am executed...". How did you execute that command? I doubt that you typed 70,000 numbers, so how did you get c(0.080172405,0.06233087,0.04315185,...) into the command line? And, did you copy/paste that into the command line (or your editor)?

Comment: I wrote this command in a file and imported that code in R (file-> Source R code)

Comment: @user, Using your method, I just loaded 1.0 million data values without any problems.   You have trash in your data somewhere.

Comment: You are right and see the selected answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a newline partway through the file, which is causing that section to look something like (replacing that newline with a space) and so after the space, there's an unexpected numeric constant.

```
... 0.0068243323,0.0733 7422182,0.07379706 ...
```

Here's how I found it:

```
b <- scan(file, what=character(0))
length(b)
```

The length is 2, not 1.

It can be read in as is like this:

```
b <- paste(b, collapse="")
b <- substring(b, 3, nchar(b)-1)
b <- strsplit(b,",")[[1]]
b2 <- as.numeric(b)
```

Comment: You're welcome, though please note the other suggestions in the comments about better ways to read in data like this.

Answer (score 9):

The 5682-th entry is `"0.0733 7422182"`, which has a space.

I think this is a simple problem of data processing.

Comment: I found the same problem as Triad, I copied, pasted into excel, copy again, paste special - transpose. and it worked like a charm with read.csv()